# Installing RStudio from source on Ubuntu 10.04 requiring newer versions of R

Tags: r, unix, ubuntu, cmake, rstudio

When trying to install RStudio on Ubuntu 10.04 from source R needs to be pre-installed, having gone through a bunch of steps to install the latest version of R (i.e. version 2.14.1), when trying to use the cmake function to install RStudio it still throws up an error saying that my version is too old and i need at least R version 2.11.

From the error message I have looked at the CMakeLists.txt, but am not really too sure what to do in order to make it point to the correct newer version of R.

Below is an illustration of the issue it was created on an EC2 instance.

Any help would be appreciated...

```
hideyoshi@ip-10-77-70-100:~$ R

R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22)
Copyright (C) 2011 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
ISBN 3-900051-07-0
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> q()
Save workspace image? [y/n/c]: n
hideyoshi@ip-10-77-70-100:~$ cd rstudio
hideyoshi@ip-10-77-70-100:~/rstudio$ cmake -DRSTUDIO_TARGET=Desktop -    DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
-- Found R: /usr/lib64/R
CMake Error at src/cpp/CMakeLists.txt:178 (message):
  Minimum R version (2.11.1) not found.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

and here is the CMakeLists.txt file

```
hideyoshi@ip-10-77-70-100:~/rstudio/src/cpp$ cat CMakeLists.txt     
#
# CMakeLists.txt
#
# Copyright (C) 2009-11 by RStudio, Inc.
#
# This program is licensed to you under the terms of version 3 of the
# GNU Affero General Public License. This program is distributed WITHOUT
# ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTY, INCLUDING THOSE OF NON-INFRINGEMENT,
# MERCHANTABILITY OR FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. Please refer to the
# AGPL (http://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.txt) for more details.
#
#

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project (RSTUDIO_CPP)

# include globals (normally these are included at the root but we also
# include them here to support cpp only configurations for development)
include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../CMakeGlobals.txt")

# global directives
add_definitions(-DBOOST_ENABLE_ASSERT_HANDLER)

# UNIX specific global directivies
if(UNIX)
   # cmake modules
   include(CheckFunctionExists REQUIRED)
   include(CheckSymbolExists REQUIRED)

   # need pkgconfig for pango cairo on linux
   if(NOT APPLE)
      find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
   endif()

   # compiler flags
   add_definitions(-Wall -pthread)

   # workaround boost bug (https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/4568)
   # by disabling kqueue support. note that this bug was fixed in boost 1.45
   add_definitions(-DBOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_KQUEUE)

   # if present, set osx deployment target variables from environment vars
   if(APPLE)
      if(NOT $ENV{CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT} STREQUAL "")
         set(CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT $ENV{CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT})
         message(STATUS "Set CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT to ${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT}")    
      endif()
      if(NOT $ENV{CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET} STREQUAL "")
         set(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET $ENV{CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET})
         message(STATUS "Set CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to         ${CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET}")
      endif()
   endif()

   # gcc hardending options (see: http://wiki.debian.org/Hardening)
   if(NOT APPLE)
      add_definitions(-Wformat -Wformat-security)
      add_definitions(-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2)
      add_definitions(-fstack-protector --param ssp-buffer-size=4)
      add_definitions(-pie -fPIE)
      set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now")
   endif()

# Win32 specific global directives
else()
   add_definitions(-DWINVER=0x501)

   if(RSTUDIO_SESSION_WIN64)

      # increase stack size to 10MB, avoid mingw auto-importing warning,
      set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,--stack=0x00a00000,--enable-auto-import")

      add_definitions(-D_WIN64
                      -D_WIN64_WINNT=0x0501
                      -D_WIN64_IE=0x600
                      -DWIN64_LEAN_AND_MEAN
                      -DBOOST_USE_WINDOWS_H)
   else()

      # increase stack size to 10MB, avoid mingw auto-importing warning,
      # and ensure that we are large address aware
      set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,--stack=0x00a00000,--enable-auto-import,--large-address-aware")

      add_definitions(-D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501
                      -D_WIN32_IE=0x600
                      -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN)
   endif()

    endif()

# determine whether we should statically link boost. we always do this
# unless we are building a non-packaged build on linux (in which case
# boost dynamic libraries are presumed to be installed on the system ldpath)
if(APPLE OR WIN32 OR RSTUDIO_PACKAGE_BUILD)
   set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
endif()

if(APPLE OR WIN32)
   # Require Boost 1.44 on Windows and Mac to avoid bugs in Boost Filesystem v2
   # that cause the process to abort instead of returning errors
   set(BOOST_VERSION 1.44.0)
else()
   set(BOOST_VERSION 1.42.0)
endif()
list(APPEND BOOST_LIBS
   date_time
   filesystem
   iostreams
   program_options
   regex
   signals
   system
   thread
)

# UNIX BOOST
if(UNIX)
   # prefer static link to /usr/local/include/boost (our custom built version)
   if(EXISTS /usr/local/include/boost AND
      EXISTS /usr/local/lib/libboost_system.a)

      # find headers
      set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
      set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR /usr/local/include)
      find_package(Boost ${BOOST_VERSION} REQUIRED)

      # define library list manually (find_package doesn't always pick them up)
      set(BOOST_LIB_DIR /usr/local/lib)
      foreach(BOOST_LIB ${BOOST_LIBS})
         list(APPEND Boost_LIBRARIES ${BOOST_LIB_DIR}/libboost_${BOOST_LIB}.a)
      endforeach()
   else()
      find_package(Boost ${BOOST_VERSION} REQUIRED COMPONENTS ${BOOST_LIBS})
   endif()

# WIN32 BOOST
else()
     # hard-code to our own prebuilt boost libs
     if(RSTUDIO_SESSION_WIN64)
        set(BOOST_ROOT "${RSTUDIO_WINDOWS_DEPENDENCIES_DIR}/boost-win/boost64")
     else()
        set(BOOST_ROOT "${RSTUDIO_WINDOWS_DEPENDENCIES_DIR}/boost-win/boost32")
     endif()
     set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR "${BOOST_ROOT}/include/boost-1_44")

   find_package(Boost ${BOOST_VERSION} REQUIRED COMPONENTS ${BOOST_LIBS})
endif()

# core library
add_subdirectory(core)

# are we in CORE_DEV mode? if so then just add the core/dev project
# otherwise, add the rest of our projects
if(RSTUDIO_CONFIG_CORE_DEV)

   add_subdirectory(core/dev)

else()

   # find LibR
   if(RSTUDIO_SESSION_WIN64)
      set(LIBR_FIND_WINDOWS_64BIT TRUE)
   endif()
   find_package(LibR REQUIRED)

   # verify we got the required R version
   if(LIBR_FOUND AND RSTUDIO_VERIFY_R_VERSION)
      include(CheckCSourceRuns)
      set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES ${LIBR_INCLUDE_DIRS})
      check_c_source_runs("
        #include <Rversion.h>
        int main()
        {
           int meetsRequirement = R_VERSION >= R_Version(${RSTUDIO_R_MAJOR_VERSION_REQUIRED},${RSTUDIO_R_MINOR_VERSION_REQUIRED},${RSTUDIO_R_PATCH_VERSION_REQUIRED});
           return !meetsRequirement;
        }"
        LIBR_MINIMUM_VERSION)
      if(NOT LIBR_MINIMUM_VERSION)
         message(FATAL_ERROR "Minimum R version (${RSTUDIO_R_MAJOR_VERSION_REQUIRED}.${RSTUDIO_R_MINOR_VERSION_REQUIRED}.${RSTUDIO_R_PATCH_VERSION_REQUIRED}) not found.")
      endif()
   endif()

   # r library
   add_subdirectory(r)

   # initialize subdirectories
   file(MAKE_DIRECTORY conf)

   # add desktop subprojects if we aren't building in server only mode
   if(RSTUDIO_DESKTOP)

      add_subdirectory(desktop)
      configure_file(rdesktop-dev.in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/rdesktop-dev)
      configure_file(conf/rdesktop-dev.conf ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/conf/rdesktop-dev.conf)

   endif()

   # add this after desktop so it is not included in fixup_bundle
   # processing which we do in desktop
   add_subdirectory(session)


   # add server subprojects if we aren't building in desktop only mode
   if(RSTUDIO_SERVER)

      add_subdirectory(server)

      configure_file(rserver-dev ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/rserver-dev)
      configure_file(conf/rserver-dev.conf ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/conf/rserver-dev.conf)
      configure_file(conf/rsession-dev.conf ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/conf/rsession-dev.conf)

   endif()

endif()
```

Comment: Why from source?  RStudio comes in a .deb file you can install.

Answer (score 4):

This problem can be solved by installing latest version of R from cran. For Ubuntu 10.04 you can do that by adding `deb http://mirrors.softliste.de/cran/bin/linux/ubuntu lucid/` to `/etc/apt/sources.list` and then performing an upgrade.

Once it's done, you can install the latest version of R by `apt-get install r-base`.

When that's complete you may rebuild after removing and recreating your build directory.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, it's LibR library that you wish to be newer.

Try to set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable to the prefix where you have newer version installed and rerun configuration process.

If it doesn't work, add `NO_DEFAULT_PATH` clause into this line:

```
find_package(LibR REQUIRED NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
```